# Heroku blocked HTTP REST API forced to use HTTPS

Tags: json, rest, http, heroku, https

I tried to deploy a little node.js app that uses an API REST service from a third party. This API provides me some json served over a URL with HTTP

Now when I deployed the app on Heroku it wil not fetch the data from the API.

This error i got in my inspector

> Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ''.     This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It forces me to use HTTPS but I don't own that API, does this mean I cannot use it simply because it's not served over HTTPS or is there a workaround so I can still deploy the application and acces the API over HTTP?

Comment: Are you certain the third-party doesn't support HTTPS? That's pretty unusual for an API in 2020.

Comment: You are right I googled more about the API and did support HTTPS, i didn't think it would support HTTPS. But i am still curious if there are ways to use HTTP with Heroku?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Heroku. It's called "mixed content". If your site is HTTPS, all the assets loaded on it need to be HTTPS. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content